# Use of "going to " in a sentence

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, difference

I read this in a story:

Mom, why can’t I go
to the circus?” David
sniffled.
“Because you are
too sick. I’m sorry,
Sweetie, we are just
going to have to find
something else to do.”

I am curious why the writer has used "we are just going to have to..."
If I simply write :" ...we have to find something else to do." Would it change the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*We have to find something else to do* would sound rather abrupt and unfeeling. The mother is sorry that her son is too ill to go to the circus, so she explains as gently as possible that they will need to think of some other way to amuse themselves.

In this context *just* means *simply* - it is the only thing they can do in the circumstances.

Comment: I think "have to find something else" sounds so abrupt because it's a tense change too — "going to" = "will", which the OP dropped when rephrasing. "We will (simply) have to find something else to do" sounds less immediate